# How to efficiently clear a field using excel vba while scraping?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to clear a field before populating it with a number. I overcame my problem by using the code below but is there a more efficient way of doing this? That is am I able to move the cursor directly to the start of the field without tabing and clear the whole field without sending individual deletes?

```
.SendKeys ("<Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab>")
            .SendKeys ("<Delete>")
            .SendKeys ("<Delete>")
            .SendKeys ("<Delete>")
            .SendKeys ("<Delete>")
            .SendKeys ("<Delete>")
            .SendKeys ("<Delete>")
            .Putstring cardno, 9, 29
```

Comment: Can you provide an URL?

Comment: @QHarr I am scraping to an AS400 screen not a website.

Comment: Oh..my bad. Will delete answer. I guess that means you cannot specify number of times to repeat (e.g. Application.SendKeys "{TAB 15}")  nor use .Clear on input field?

Comment: @QHarr Appreciate your time. Using .SendKeys ("<Clear>") clears the whole screen not just the field. Will try your Application.SendKeys "{TAB 15}")  though.

Comment: Clear is a method applied to an input element in html not as sendkeys.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42133930/4934172) might be related.

Comment: usually the `Home` key moves the caret to the beginning, or `Ctrl` + `Left`